# Major problem with libxcursor1:amd64

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and have a problem with `libxcursor1:amd64` which is causing everything to run really slow and not allow packages to be updated.

I have tried `apt-get -f install` to fix things and got this:

```
dpkg: error processing package libxcursor1:amd64 (--configure):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
libxcursor1:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried to force it to remove the package and reinstall it (failed). I have tried going into recovery mode and running it before everything loads, and this failed. Really stuck, as the laptop is unusable.

Thanks,
Dom.

Comment: At first check your repositories. You may follow [this great answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/66509) for screenshots and commands. I do not have any problems installing mentioned package on my 16.04 LTS system.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: for some reason, synaptic managed to reinstall the package in place, whereas I couldn't get it to reinstall using the command line. Anyway, it is fixed, so, I guess the lesson is go for the simple answer first...

Thanks to N0rbert for the help.